# LwIP TCP can't receive > 1460 Bytes datas?

Tags: lwip

I had a problem when receiving data with TCP LwIP: Because TCP max segment size is 1460 so I can not receive the whole response from the server (2.75KB), I just received only 1440 Bytes. Are there any ways to receive full the response data?
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the [`IP_REASSEMBLY`](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__lwip__opts__ipv4.html#ga1a31ab0e0f37b17d40fa7c35bc2c4f69) option from LwIP according to its document for incoming packets reassembly and enable [`IP_FRAG`](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__lwip__opts__ipv4.html#gaf85c8bdd5035b6cada790b4cc2a209a4) for outgoing packets reassembly.